# Memory game card flipping problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse, handler

I'm working on a simple memory game where you basically match the same cards. I want the cards to be able to flip back if both didn't match. The flipping codes are the following:

```
 mT1.unselect();
 mT2.unselect();
```

When i put it in the else statement the cards flip back immediately so i used a handler to slow it down.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                     public void run() { 
                         mT1.unselect();
                         mT2.unselect();
                         playSound( SOUND_FAILED );
                     } 
                }, 2000);
```

But when i test it doesn't flip back, but the sound is played after the given time. What's the problem?

Full code:

```
   public void onPosition(int position)
{
    if (position == mLastPosition)
    {

        return;
    }
    mLastPosition = position;
    Tile tile = mList.get(position);
    tile.select();
    int sound = tile.mResId % mSounds.length;
    playSound(sound);

    switch (mSelectedCount)
    {
        case 0:
            mT1 = tile;
            break;

        case 1:
            mT2 = tile;
            if (mT1.getResId() == mT2.getResId())
            {
                mT1.setFound(true);
                mT2.setFound(true);
                mFoundCount += 2;
                playSound(SOUND_SUCCEED);
            }
            else
            {

                Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                     public void run() { 
                         mT1.unselect();
                         mT2.unselect();
                         playSound( SOUND_FAILED );
                     } 
                }, 2000); 

            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if (mT1.getResId() != mT2.getResId())
            {

            }
            mSelectedCount = 0;
            mT1 = tile;
            break;
    }
    mSelectedCount++;
    mMoveCount++;
    updateView();
    checkComplete();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory game problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926462/memory-game-problems)

Comment: You have problem in your function mT1.unslect() and mT2.unselect().mention your these functions too

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't get it.

Comment: Code of unselect method?

Comment: private static final String ATTR_SELECTED = "Selected";



 mSelected = object.getBoolean(ATTR_SELECTED);





public void unselect()
    {
        mSelected = false;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your previous question, you've still not given us enough context, but I'll have a wild stab in the dark - maybe you need to call:

```
updateView();
```

in your `Runnable`'s `run()` method.

Maybe if you post your `updateView()` method and some more context of how it works, we might be able to help more if this guess doesn't fix it.

Comment: it actually worked!! thank you so much man! i apologize for not providing enough information twice.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. This question was better than your last one as it gave more information about what you'd tried, but without the code for your `unselect()` method or `updateView()` it's very difficult to guess what it does. It was only when seeing your `unselect()` code in your answer to @Tarikhelian that I could see that it didn't update the UI and could therefore guess you might need to call `updateView()`. Hopefully you'll get better at knowing what information is relevant to your questions as you keep developing and using stackoverflow. Good luck!